# How do I use an older Java version without downgrading?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm trying to run a minecraft server (version 1.6.4). Forge seems to get very upset if I try to use Java 8 with it, so how do I use an older version without uninstalling Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

**Nevermind.** I'm currently working on a solution; this includes installing `openjdk-7-jre` and using the `java7` command (to my knowledge; untested).